# Health-Related Quality of Life (HRQoL) questionnaire for 6-year olds

Tags: measurement, health-psychology

I am looking for a cross-national Health-Related Quality of Life (HRQoL) for 6-year olds. The closest I found is the [KidScreen project](https://www.kidscreen.org/english/project/):

> Three versions of the KIDSCREEN questionnaire are targeted at children, adolescents and parents. They are available in various languages and can be applied for multiple research goals.
>
> KIDSCREEN-52 (long version) covers ten HRQoL dimensions, KIDSCREEN-27 (short version) covers five HRQoL dimensions, while the KIDSCREEN-10 Index encompasses a global HRQoL measurement.
>
> In this fashion the questionnaires measure the quality of life from the child's point of view with regard to physical, mental and social well-being.

But it [starts at 8 years of age](https://www.kidscreen.org/english/questionnaires/):

> The KIDSCREEN instruments assess children’s and adolescents’ subjective health and well-being. They were developed as self-report measures applicable for healthy and chronically ill children and adolescents aged from 8 to 18 years. As a result of their simultaneous development in 13 European countries, the KIDSCREEN instruments are truly cross-national HRQoL measures.

The [homepage](https://www.kidscreen.org/english/project/) mentions a recommendation by the International Consortium for Health Outcomes Measurement (ICHOM):

> The KIDSCREEN-10 is recommended by the International Consortium for Health Outcomes Measurement (ICHOM) as part of their standard set of outcome measures for child and youth anxiety, depression, obsessive-compulsive disorder and post traumatic stress disorder.

So I looked on [their website](https://www.ichom.org) but could not find a similar recommendation for 6-year olds.

How can I find a validated and cross-national questionnaire for Health-Realted Quality of Life of 6-year olds?